# Clearing cache in XRM 2011 with ObjectCacheManager

Tags: dynamics-crm, xrm

In the old days, I had this 
http://arens.ws/wordpress/?p=54

```
public static void ClearCache(string entityName)
{
  const string format = "adxdependency:crm:entity:{0}";
  var dependency = string.Format(format, entityName).ToLower();

  var cache = Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Caching.CacheManager.GetBaseCache();
  cache.Remove(dependency);
}
```

In 2011 it's different. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It has changed only a little bit:

```
ObjectCache cache = Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Caching.ObjectCacheManager
    .GetInstance("Xrm");
string cachekey = String.Format("xrm:dependency:entity:{0}:id={1:D}", 
    entity.LogicalName, entity.Id);
cache.Remove(cachekey);
```

I found no documentation for this, found the key naming scheme by enumerating the cache. Probably using this is not a best practice, it could change again in the next version? There should be a better way to do this...

[Update]
There is a [better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201116/clearing-cache-in-xrm-2011-with-objectcachemanager/10003527).

Try this:

```
var serviceContext = (Get an OrganizationServiceContext);

var serviceContainer = serviceContext as 
                           OrganizationServiceContainer;
var cachedOrgService = serviceContainer.Service as 
                           CachedOrganizationService;
var orgServiceCache = cachedOrgService.Cache as 
                           IOrganizationServiceCache;
var entity = (Get the entity that was updated);

orgServiceCache.Remove(entity.LogicalName, entity.Id);
```

Works like a charm...